# How can I put a Medium article on my personal website?

Tags: embed, medium

I want to include a full Medium article on my personal website. I know it's possible because it has been done [here](https://thebillfold.com/theories-on-my-thrift-store-dog-mugs-or-who-paid-money-to-have-these-manufactured-562f9d5632a4#.6wa8ic5kk). (Notice the domain is *not* `medium.com`.)

If you click on `...` on the bottom-right of a Medium article, and then click 'Embed story', you will be given a script, e.g.

```
<script async src="https://static.medium.com/embed.js"></script><a class="m-story" data-collapsed="true" href="https://thebillfold.com/theories-on-my-thrift-store-dog-mugs-or-who-paid-money-to-have-these-manufactured-562f9d5632a4">Theories on My Thrift Store Dog Mugs, Or: Who Paid Money to Have These Manufactured?</a>
```

The problem is that this embed is just the title and abstract. The full Medium article text is not included.

How can I embed a full Medium.com article on my personal website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That’s not an embedded article, it’a [custom domain for Medium](https://medium.com/the-story/custom-domains-for-publications-8cb161d9651#.veb6wnacs). See [here](https://medium.com/the-story/move-your-domain-to-medium-21fd74abbbe6#.bbclisiw6) for more details.

You need to create a [Medium Publication](https://medium.com/@Medium/publications-d23372baede0#.wgaeg4f3m) in order to be able to publish with Medium on your own domain.

---

As per [Medium Help](https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/216566288-Can-I-embed-Medium-on-other-sites-), the embedding feature is no longer supported.

> ## Can I embed Medium on other sites?
>
> Medium embeds on other sites are no longer supported.

<del>Regarding the embedding process, check the following note on the [Embed Medium Anywhere](https://medium.com/@Medium/embed-medium-anywhere-3eaed64aed8a#.ffoac1b5a) help page.</del>

> <del>**Important**: Some blog services strip script tags and this prevents Medium embeds from functioning. ☹</del>

<del>So that might be your problem.</del>

<del>Also, apparently, only the title and abstract of the post are embedded, not the full text.</del>

Comment: All 3 of the links are dead. Look here instead: https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005579728-Get-started-with-custom-domains

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue as well and have been trying to figure out a solution for the last few days. There were a couple of articles I found which had old ways to do it but these didn't work anymore.

I ended up figuring out how to do this using the api from rsstojson.com and then using the generated JSON. You could do this for a single post or for all of your blog posts.

I detailed how I did this on my blog [here](https://medium.jasonmdesign.com/display-medium-articles-on-your-site-d772b3b05779) and also set up a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/jasonm4130/pen/vZYbQx) for you to have a closer look if my post isn't too clear.

Comment: Does this require the membership fee to work? I've tried codepen with my username for medium but keep getting 404 and not json.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem.

After reading a few blogs, I came up with my own solution.

You will need to use the rss2json converter - https://rss2json.com as you will get a CORS error if you directly access the JSON content from [medium.com/@username/latest?format=json](https://medium.com/@medium/latest?format=json). Then, you can use the rss2json API to retrieve your latest blog posts and display them on your webpage.

Furthermore, I have written a blog post on this solution [here](https://snpranav.com/blog/medium-posts-on-website/?utm_medium=answer&utm_source=webapps.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can enter code into a Medium article on MacOS by doing the following:

```
Command + Option + 6
```

On Windows, this equates to:

```
Ctrl + Alt + 6.
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. This answer was automatically marked as low quality. Please add a brief description about how this answer the question.